# SharePoint 2013 Document Library Cannot edit folder/file permissions

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions

I get the following error when trying to edit a file permission or folder permission in document library from either the dropdown or from the ribbon. anyone seen this before:

[image: Unexpected response data from server]

Below is the event viewer message:

> WebHost failed to process a request.  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/41552038 
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/_vti_bin/client.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during
>   compilation.  The exception message is: A binding instance has already
>   been associated to listen URI 'http://ServerName/_vti_bin/client.svc'.
>   If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also
>   share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints
>   were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file,
>   or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config. . --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: A binding instance has already been
>   associated to listen URI 'http://ServerName/_vti_bin/client.svc'. If
>   two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share
>   the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were
>   either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a
>   combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHost.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)  Process
>   Name: w3wp  Process ID: 20640

Comment: Can you check Access Request Setting allows Sharing for Folder and files under Site Permissions

Comment: the option is missing. I will see if something is turned off in settings

Comment: Well this is new. I had to enable outgoing email for this menu to show up. The ARS (Access Request Settings) are set to allow access requests. checking the document library.  I can now share the library. However when i try to check who the document or library is shared with it still shows the above error.